# How can I know when a certificate was created?

Tags: certificates, heartbleed

I want to know whether my various providers changed their certificate because of Heartbleed, or they are using an old vulnerable certificate. How can I know that? Is the "valid from" date also the creation date?

Comment: I was under the impression that Heartbleed is a code issue, not a certificate issue / not mitigated by changing the certificate. Perhaps you could supply a reference to support your assumption?

Comment: Heartbleed is indeed a code issue, but since there is no way of confirming if you've been compromised, it's advisable to generate new certificates with a new private key after you've updated OpenSSL.

Comment: I would take it to mean that he is interested to see if the sites he uses opt to generate new keys after patching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heartbleed has pretty little relation with certificates. The only link is that a *potential* consequence of a successfully exploited heartbleed is a reveal of the SSL server private key. Therefore you *might* want to go to full paranoia mode and consider that any private key which was used in a vulnerable server is toast and must be replaced. This is quite extremist, and somehow misses the point because the same argument applies to every single remotely exploitable buffer overflow ever discovered in the server, and there are several of them each year; singling out the "heartbleed" bug is unwarranted.

---

Now a certificate contains two "validity dates", called `notBefore` and `notAfter`. **Usually**, the `notBefore` date is close to the date at which the certificate was actually issued, i.e. when the CA signed it. Normally, the `notBefore` date is slightly in the past because the CA wants to produce a certificate that the owner can immediately use even if his machines' clocks are not accurate. For instance, Microsoft's CA ("Certificate Services"), by default, will write "14:35" as `notBefore` time if the certificate was really issued at 14:45. Other CA may go further; I know of one CA which systematically used midnight (from the previous night) as `notBefore` time.

But you must note that this date qualifies the date of issuance of the *certificate*, not of the *key*. It is relatively common to "renew" a certificate by issuing a new certificate (with new validity dates) containing the *same* public key and identity as in a previous certificate. For the "heartbleed exploit" scenario above, you worry about whether the potentially leaked private key was discarded and regenerated or not. Nothing in the certificate contents will tell you anything about the time at which the private key was created (well, the private key existed before the certificate, but maybe *long* before, or maybe not; the certificate contents won't tell).

---

Let's get a bit more real here. Heartbleed is just one more *potentially exploitable* bug in an implementation; this is not the first one, and not the last one. Probability that any given server was exploited between the time the bug was discovered, and the time the server's code was fixed, is extremely low on average. The bug became all the rage overnight, but was not observed in the wild before.

Comment: I'll disagree with you here for two reasons: (1) the exploit is trivial to implement, so it could have been exploited almost immediately upon disclosure and (2) the exploit leaves no evidence, so we might not be aware of it in the wild. I agree that the chances of private key disclosure are low, but the hassle of updating your keys and certificates post-patch is a relatively minor one (per server, at least, if you have a large number of domains/certificates the effort scales linearly)... a little paranoia isn't a bad thing if it only requires a minor effort to satisfy.

Comment: I agree on disagreeing. CloudFlare has proven that private keys _can_ be stolen (in less than 12 hours), so this should not be taken lightly. If regular buffer overruns which occur more often might have the same effect, it is bad that they are not highlighted in the same way in the community -- nevertheless a misbehaviour for this type of bugs is no excuse for taking this bug lightly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) and [specifications](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459.txt) a certificate does not hold information regarding the creation date.

Answer (score -1):

Take my chrome as an example, in the url, there's a green lock:

[image: green lock]

when you click the green lock, you will see:

[image: certificate information]

when click "certificate information", you will see the certificate, click details, you can see:

[image: certificate detail]

the "not valid before" is when the certificate create. Actually in this case, since Yahoo is affected, so its certificate is issued just today.

Meanwhile you can find any site who are affected [here](https://github.com/musalbas/heartbleed-masstest/blob/master/top1000.txt), I have tried some of them, some of the certificates are updated, while some are still not.